# delete MySQL entire database. Database not showing in MySQL Databases

Tags: mysql, database

Every time I create a database using a custom joomla template quick install the database is created but does not show up in MySQL Database management despite the fact that it most definitely does exist and MySQL database management knows it does because it wont let me create a database with that name due to error "Database already exists".

I want to delete joomlasall database.

[image: http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/4995/tempkh.png]

Full size image

http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/4995/tempkh.png

Comment: alternatively, if u knows where u have saved it u can delete it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not see database but you are sure that it exists, this is definitely permissions issue.

Do

```
SHOW GRANTS
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-grants.html)

You will see that you does not hold global SELECT privilege.
You need to explicitly GRANT permissions with similar command like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Instead of ALL you can specify SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE , EXECUTE, etc... [check this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

replace DBNAME with your DB name, username with user for whom you want to grant access and localhost with hostname if DB is used remotly.

To do this, you need GRANT privilege or to be root user.

Answer (score 0):

use same mysql user credentials for Joomla DB connectivity also the one you are using in phpmyadmin.